# How to break when DOM node with specific id loaded

Tags: google-chrome, dom

All

Thanks for help. I get one question about chrome debug tool which is:

How can I break on certain Node loaded or attribute changed. For example, I have a div element, its id is printable, I want to debug(break) what it looks like when this node first loaded in. Or by another way, how can I break when that #printable applied a size style?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break within Chrome tools in three situations for any element:

1. Subtree has been modified
2. Attributes for element have been modified
3. Node itself has been removed from the DOM

In the below example, I have selected a 'section' on the Google News page, and set to break on when subtree gains more elements:

[image: Right-click on element, 'Break on...' menu]

Clicking the 'More Entertainment Stories' link adds in more article elements, and the break will occur.